# What is ${\rm Im}(z)+{\rm Re}(z)=1$?

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers

I've started studying complex numbers and I am having conceptual difficulties when asked to plot the equation $${\rm Im}(z)+{\rm Re}(z)=1$$

How do I graph it ?I can't see the analogy with the Cartesian coordinate system.

For example let's say that ${\rm Re}(z)=2$ then ${\rm Im}(z)=-1$, but what is this point on the imaginaries axis?

Do I have to interpret ${\rm Im}(z)=-1$ as $ai=-1$ then solve for $a$?
I am really confused.

Comment: Hint: $z=x+\mathrm iy$. What does the equation $x+y=1$ describe?

Comment: You know about the Argand Plane?

Comment: @celtschk Yes ,I had the intuition of a line,but I don't know how to translate it into this coordinate frame.(My slope should be the coefficient of $Re(z)$ ?)

Comment: @Aniket Nope.What is it ?

Comment: @Mr.Y Check this link  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Complex_plane and also this http://mathworld.wolfram.com/ArgandDiagram.html

Comment: @Aniket Ah,that is just the complex plane.Yes I do know that.

Comment: Then you know the equation and you have to plot it on the complex plane. What problem do you face now? AND $Im(z)=y \not = iy$... if it helps.

Comment: I think I am making some dumb conceptual mistake.If I interpret $Im(z)$ as my $y$ coordinate then $Im(z)=1-Re(z)$ is a real number so how can I know where I am in the $y$ coordinate ?

Comment: Just plot the line y=1-x. Label the y-axis Im, and the x-axis Re. And that's it. I think you're making it more complicated than it is. Say you plot the point x=1,y=-3. That represents the complex number 1-3i.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Plug $z=x+yi$, where $x,y\in\mathbb{R}$. Then

$${\rm{Im}}(x+yi)+{\rm{Re}}(x+yi)=1$$
$$y+x=1$$
$$y=1-x$$

Comment: Ah..so if I have for example $Re(z)=2$ then $Im(z)=-1 \implies y=-3i$ .Does it work like that ?Thanks for you time.

Comment: When ${\rm Re}(z)=2$ then ${\rm Im}(z)=-1$ and you have a point $(2,-1)$ on the complex plane. Its corresponding number is equal to $2-i$. Check it: $${\rm Re}(2-i)+{\rm Im}(2-i)=1\implies 2-1=1$$

Comment: x is just the real part of the complex number. y is just the complex part of the complex number without the i. So if Re(z) =2 and Im(z)=-1, x=2 and y=-1. And the point represents the complex number 2-i. And note this point (2,-1) lies on the line y=1-x.

Comment: @AmeetSharma Yeah you've got me.I thought that $Im(z)$ was the entire  $ai$ thing because in my book the imaginaries axis has $ i,2i,3i$ ...that was the origin of my problems.Thank you as always guys !

Comment: Remember Im(z) is a real number. It's the complex part of the number without the i. So any complex number can be written as z = Re(z) + i*Im(z), where Re(z) and Im(z) are both real numbers.